# VBA Clicking Button on IE

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, vba

I use VBA a lot, but I'm still a beginner when it comes to IE automation.
I need to create a code to click a "button" on a specific website for my company.
This button opens up a small menu where I need to select a few things (I'll deal with that later I guess). Thing is, the button doesn't show any ID or name, it's a span and I'm having trouble making it click it.
Below is the HTML when I press F12 and inspect the element over the button:

```
 <span class="search_for_watchers">
 <a href="/watchers/new?project_id=pendencia" data-method="get" data-remote="true">Procurar por outros observadores para adiconar</a>
 </span>
```

I've tried so many suggestions that I found over the internet.. I've tried getting the element by ID, name, class name, etc, but no success.
Below is the code I'm using:

```
Sub Automate_IE_Load_Page()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ie.Visible = True

    URL = "Examplesite.com"

    ie.Navigate URL

    Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."

    Do While ie.READYSTATE = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ie.READYSTATE = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Application.StatusBar = URL & " Loaded"

    botao = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("search_for_watchers")
    botao.Click
End Sub
```

It doesn't show any error.. it just doesn't open up the sub-menu I want to, therefore the button isn't clicked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getElementsByClassName is plural; i.e. it represents a collection. The following represents the first object with this class then clicks the first anchor tag within.

```
ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("search_for_watchers")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).click
```

If you want to assign an object var to the element and then use the var to click, you need to Set the var.

Comment: Thank you sir. Didn' know there was even a plural. That means there is another class with that name? Weird haha. Anyways, it's working perfectly now ;)

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns a collection of all the elements with that particular class name; there could be one or a dozen or none.

Answer (score 1):

You enter endless loop here twice:

```
Do While ie.READYSTATE = 4: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ie.READYSTATE = 4: DoEvents: Loop
```

E.g., it looks like this:

```
Do While ie.READYSTATE = 4
    DoEvents
Loop
```

but the `:` are instead of a new line in VBA.

---

Make sure to change a bit the loop, thus something like this:

```
Do While NOT ie.READYSTATE = 4: DoEvents: Loop
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't run the entire code yet, so didn't even notice this. Will try your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You could also loop through the  tags and find the one you want to click, like so:

```
Set tags = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each tagx In tags
    If tagx.innerText = "Procurar por outros observadores para adiconar" Then
        tagx.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```